# (React) Dynamic dropdown box examples. HowTo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

Can anyone point me in the direction of any dynamic React drop-down box examples?

I wish to implement drop-down functionality, which will take the result of a primary drop-down selection, to determine the output of a secondary drop-down list. For example, selecting 'London' from a primary drop-down list, will populate a secondary drop-down box with regions (boroughs) within London.

I'm planning to populate the drop-down boxes by selecting data from a firebasedb.

Comment: Perhaps check [this](https://react.rocks/tag/Dropdown)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the list of options of select box in react dynamically from your props or state. **Run the snippet below for an example** on how this could look like.

Also check out [react's docs for more info on `<select>` elements](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag) in react.

```js
class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.handleFirstLevelChange = this.handleFirstLevelChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSecondLevelChange = this.handleSecondLevelChange.bind(this)
    
    // Prepopulate with the first item for each level
    this.state = {
      firstLevel: Object.keys(props.options)[0],
      secondLevel: Object.keys(props.options)[0][0]
    }
  }
  
  handleFirstLevelChange(event) {
    this.setState({firstLevel: event.target.value});
  }
  
  handleSecondLevelChange(event) {
    this.setState({secondLevel: event.target.value});
  }
  
  render() {
    const renderOption = item => <option value={item}>{item}</option>

    const firstLevelOptions = Object.keys(this.props.options).map(renderOption)
    const secondLevelOptions = this.props.options[this.state.firstLevel].map(renderOption)
    
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <select onChange={this.handleFirstLevelChange} value={this.state.firstLevel}>
            {firstLevelOptions}
          </select>
        </p>
        <p>
          <select onChange={this.handleSecondLevelChange} value={this.state.secondLevel}>
            {secondLevelOptions}
          </select>
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const options = {
  "USA": ["New York", "San Francisco"],
  "Germany": ["Berlin", "Munich"]
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyForm options={options} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'></div>
```